# Cohen-Macaulay ring and module: R-regular vs M-regular

Tags: commutative-algebra, cohen-macaulay

Let $R$ be a Cohen-Macaulay ring and $M$ be a finite generated maximal Cohen-Macaulay module. I know that the [R-regular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_sequence#Definitions) sequence must be [$M$-regular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_sequence#Definitions). Here are my questions:

1) Must an $M$-regular sequence also be $R$-regular?

2) If $M$ is not maximal, is an $R$-regular sequence also $M$-regular?

Comment: I know commutative algebra it's must know these two types of sequences by heart, but could you consider adding the definitions? You don't have to, of course, but it enhances the question, if you ask me.

Comment: OK, maybe I should add this wiki link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_sequence

Comment: I went ahead and incorporated the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Consider $R=K[X,Y]/(X^2Y)$ and $M=R/(x)$. Then $M$ is MCM, $y$ is $M$-regular and $y$ is not $R$-regular.

2) Consider $R=K[X,Y]$ and $M=R/I$, where $I=(X)$. Then $X,Y$ is not $M$-regular.